# Calling SAP web service using jquery ajax

Tags: web-services, sap-basis, netweaver

Can anybody please give me a start to "calling a SAP web service using jquery ajax method in
html5 page".I am in great need of it.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanking all in advance.

Comment: Example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017980/ajax-consuming-sap-web-service-not-working/34530712#34530712

Answer (score 0):

You will need to POST a SOAP request to the SAP webservice url just as you would do with a .NET webservice.

Ask the abapper that created the webservice for the wsdl of the generated webservice and do your jQuery XML request based on that.